# Simple Upload Form not Putting Associated Info into the SQL Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've written out the script and it seem to work just fine on my test server but when I try to uses it on my live server it will not insert the sql info into the table.

Here the script:

```
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect server ");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$title=$_POST['title2'];   
$description=$_POST['description'];  
$uploaded = $_POST['uploaded'];   
$target = "../../projects/forms/";   
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ;  
$ok=1;   
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target))   
 {  
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded";  
 }   
 else {  
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";  
 }

$result=MYSQL_QUERY("INSERT INTO $tbl_name(title, description, target) ". "VALUES ('$title', '$description', '$target')");  
  $id= mysql_insert_id();   
   print "File ID: <b>$id</b>";  
  print "Title: <b>$title</b>";  
  print "Description: <b>$description</b>";  
   print "File Name:</b>$target";  
   print "To upload another file Click Here<br>";
```

Comment: what error mysql reports to you if you call mysql_error() after the query?

Comment: do you get any errors at all?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, that for some reason you cannot insert data into database:

1. You provided wrong user name and password, when connecting to DB;
2. Your user has no INSERT privilege.

and several more possibilities.

You can clearly see what is wrong by calling mysql_error() after the query.

```
$result=MYSQL_QUERY("INSERT INTO $tbl_name(title, description, target) ". "VALUES ('$title', '$description', '$target')");
if (!$result){
    echo mysql_error();
}
```

This does not really have anything to do with the question, but you should always escape data you get through GET and POST before putting it into query! Otherwise you are making a big shiny security hole in your application.

```
$title=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title2']);
$description=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description']);
$uploaded = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['uploaded']);
```